# Angular 2 using GoogleMap Api. The MAP not visible when the html is rendered

Tags: angular, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am creating angular 2 app that interacts with google map api. The documentation does say that if the styles are not applied then google map would not been seen on the screen. 
Even if I explicitly assign the css class to the html element, it makes no difference. Can somebody help

As per the documentation on this link

https://angular-maps.com/docs/getting-started.html

```
.sebm-google-map-container {
  height: 300px;
}
```

I have declared it in my component however I am only able to see the title and not the map. I dont see any errors on the developer tools as well. Please see my code below

**ShipGeoFinderComponent**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'ship-root',
    templateUrl: '/app/ShipGeoFinder/ShipGeoFinder.html',
     styles: [`
    .sebm-google-map-container {
       height: 400px;
        width: 400px;
     }
  `],
})
export class ShipGeoFinderComponent {
    title: string = 'My first angular2-google-maps project';
    lat: number = 51.678418;
    lng: number = 7.809007;
}
```

**ShipGeoFinder.html**

```
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>

<!-- this creates a google map on the page with the given lat/lng from -->
<!-- the component as the initial center of the map: -->

<sebm-google-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
    <sebm-google-map-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></sebm-google-map-marker>
</sebm-google-map>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you imported the Angular Maps Module in your app.module.ts

```
    //app.module.ts        
    import { AgmCoreModule } from 'angular2-google-maps/core';

    imports: [
     AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: 'YOUR_KEY_FROM_GOOGLE_CONSOLE' //Ensure Google Maps Javascript API is enabled
     })
    ]
```

That should do the trick if you haven't done it already.